# writing parser of a simple language

Tags: java, antlr, language-design

I'm trying to design a simple language is similar to lips, schema. I have written its lexer(tokenizer). I can seperate into operators, identifiers etc. But I try now writing parser. For this, just one example is enough for me. *Can someone give me an example in java code just for the example?* Besides, everyone mentions of usage antlr. Can someone who attempts to use antlr show an example using my example in this question?

- – `EXP -> EXPI | EXPB`
- – `EXPI -> (+ EXPI EXPI) | (- EXPI EXPI) | (* EXPI EXPI) | (/ EXPI EXPI) | Id | IntegerValue | (Id EXPLIST)`
- –  `EXPB -> (and EXPB EXPB)`

if my input is `(+ 1 2)`, I hope to get as output

```
 - START-> INPUT
 - -> EXP
 - -> EXPI
 - -> (+ EXPI EXPI)
 - -> (+ EXPI Id)
 - -> (+ Id Id)
```

It is about LR(shift-reduce parsing). I have a simple example that I don't know whether I can modify the code or not for the parsing. But, a point catches my attention, stack usage is proper for LR algorithm. Doesn't it ?

```
import java.util.Stack;

public class SmallLisp {

    Stack<String> stack;

    public SmallLisp(){
        String[] tokens = new String[]{"(","+","2","(","+","3","2",")",")",};
        stack = new Stack<String>();
        for (int i=0;i<tokens.length;i++){
            stack.push(tokens[i]);
            if(tokens[i].equals(")")) Interprete();
        }
    }

    public void Interprete(){
        String tok;
        Stack<String> callStack = new Stack<String>();
        tok = stack.pop(); /* This is the ) character */
        while(!(tok=stack.pop()).equals("(")){
            callStack.push(tok);
        }
        Call(callStack);
    }

    public void Call(Stack<String> callStack){
        String func = callStack.pop(); /* This is the operator or function */
        if(func.equals("+")) {
            double result = Plus(callStack);
            stack.push(String.valueOf(result));
        }
        //if(func.equals("-")) Minus(callStack);
    }

    public double Plus(Stack<String> callStack){
        double a = Double.parseDouble(callStack.pop());
        double b = Double.parseDouble(callStack.pop());
        System.out.println("Answer is "+(a+b));
        return(a+b);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SmallLisp();
    }
}
```

Comment: The answer you seek is complicated to explain. Here are the basic principles. First, you need to write down (enumerate) all of the states that the parser will encounter. Then, you need to write a transition table that allows the parser to shift from one state to another as it encounters tokens and parses rules. You're on the right track about using a stack: each time you shift, you push a state onto that stack. When you reduce, you pop multiple states off the stack. (You're missing two critical arrays in your code that would make your parser work.)

Comment: You could also use a `switch` statement instead of a transition table (array). But you still need to know all of the parser states and how to transition between them (hint: the top of the stack is the parser's current state that you `switch` on.)

Comment: **a simple language is similar to lips, schema.** based on the tags, do you mean Lisp and Scheme?

Comment: You'll have an easier time of parsing if you don't specially case the arithmetic operators.  Just have your grammar be:  `exp ::= id | number | (exp exp exp)`.  Then, when you're *evaluating* expressions (after you've parsed them), you can complain semantic errors like a number in the function position.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor: Shouldn't that be `(oper exp exp)`, with an `oper` rule `oper -> '+' | '-' | '*' | '/'`?

Comment: @ScottM Probably not.  If this is genuinely supposed to be Lisp/Scheme-ish, then you'd want to be able to do `((lambda (x) ...) ...)`;  you'll need expressions to be able to appear as the first element of a list.  As I said, that would probably be easier to enforce in the *interpreter/evaluator*.  It's easier there to define the evaluation model as one that checks whether the first element is +, -, *, or /, and raises an error if it's not.  The question, as written, is about parsing Scheme/Lisp, and a Scheme/Lisp parser would allow other things in the first position.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor: Sorta looks a bit like a h/w assignment in basic parsing, based on a Lisp/Scheme-ish language. Hence the scope restriction to what looks like the assignment. OTOH, I could just be too cynical.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid to write your own Parser you could use [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/)

This is a parser generator that does all the work for you if you support it with a valid grammar.

If you still want to write it yourself you could still use ANTLR to see how they create their parser/lexers.

Comment: can you show an example according to my question using antlr?