# Validity of html

Tags: java, pattern-matching

I want to enter complete html throgh string and then check is the given sting is a valid html or not.

Public booleanisValidHTML(String htmlData)

Description-Checks whether a given HTML data is a valid HTML data or not

htmlData- A HTML document in the form of string which contains TAGS and data.

returns-true if the given htmlData contains all valid tags with their allowed attributes and their possible values, otherwise false.
A valid HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Page Title</title>
    </head>
 <body>
  <table style="width:100%">
     <tr>
             <td>Jill</td>
             <td>Smith</td>
             <td>50</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
           <td>Eve</td>
           <td>Jackson</td>
           <td>94</td>
     </tr>
   </table>
  <b>This text is bold</b>
  </body>
  </html>


   The java code should look like

class htmlValidator{
public static void main(String args[]){
Scanner in =new Scanner(System.in);
String html=new String("pass the html here'');
  isValidHtml(html)
  }
      public static boolean isValidHtml(String html){
      /** write code here**/
      /** method returns true if the given html is valid **
       //**please help**/
        }
```

}

Comment: Use a DOM parser.

Comment: possible duplicate :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4392505/how-to-validate-html-from-java

Comment: If you want to define your own rules for what you accept as valid HTML, you not only need to be an expert there, you also need to read a book on writing parsers, this maybe the greater of the challenges. You will learn a lot that could be useful to know at other times, though, so happy studying.

Comment: See also [Creating a parser for a simple pseudocode language?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9957873/creating-a-parser-for-a-simple-pseudocode-language) and [writing parser of a simple language](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34432136/writing-parser-of-a-simple-language). An answer to the latter refers to ANTLR, not a tool I know, may be worth checking out.

Comment: My search came across a series of articles on parser writing in Java: [Writing a Parser in Java](http://cogitolearning.co.uk/?p=523).

Answer (score 2):

Rather than writing regex to parse and check ([which is generally A Bad Idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)), you're better off using something like [jsoup](https://jsoup.org/) to parse it and check for errors.

From https://jsoup.org/cookbook/input/parse-document-from-string:

```
String html = "<html><head><title>First parse</title></head>"
    + "<body><p>Parsed HTML into a doc.</p></body></html>";
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
```

Comment: I think you got the wrong [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1553851) there.

Comment: i want to perform this my own defined method not a predefined one.

Comment: @shmosel Darn, my sneaky edit was not nearly sneaky enough!

Comment: A second too late :)

Comment: @RahulKashyap You better be an expert on HTML then.  Would this be HTML4 or HTML5?