# How to call Java method that stored in string variable

Tags: java, spring, runtime, beanshell, groovyshell

first, this is not similar to other questions because expressions contains parameters.

assume we have this method:

```
 public static int test(int x, Double y) {
    return somthing
}
```

and we have string expression like this:

```
 String expression = "test(1, 2)";
```

so how can we run this expression ?

I want to write a method with parameter and call it from a expression .

I can't find any library to solve this problem.

please help

Comment: you can write your own

Comment: Do you know what input you are going to have? For example if you are creating a calculator you can enter some expressions like: sum, divide, minus which are limited number and you know them all. Or your use case should cover any kind of method name given in the expression?

Comment: Your basically talking about writing a parser here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34432136/writing-parser-of-a-simple-language

Comment: @Aethernite I know that. I edit the question. I want to write a method with parameter and call it as a expression

Comment: @Stultuske can you tell me how?

Comment: @markspace thanks. I think you right. can you  give a good example?

Comment: for simple things like this, you can even get it by using simple String operations, what have you tried so far?

Comment: Check this thread -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/160970/how-do-i-invoke-a-java-method-when-given-the-method-name-as-a-string You can use reflection the get the method using its name but for the parameters you have to parse the string to get them. For example you can use a regex to extract them and then parse them into the wanted format.

Comment: @Stultuske assume this expression  ` "func_round(func_areaUnderCurve(x) * y + 10000)"`

Comment: @Aethernite I know that but  maybe I can find a way simpler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Script Engine with a scripting language, such as JavaScript, to handle your expressions.

```java
package expression;

import javax.script.ScriptEngine;
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager;
import javax.script.ScriptException;

public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
        ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("nashorn");
        try {
            engine.eval("var test = Packages.expression.App.test");
            Object result = engine.eval("test(1,2)");
            System.out.println(result);
        } catch (ScriptException e) {
            //TODO: handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static int test(int x, Double y) {
        return x;
    }
}
```

The line `"var test = Packages.expression.App.test"` creates an alias to your method.

The line `Object result = engine.eval("test(1,2)");` calls your method.

You need to include the following dependency to your maven pom.xml:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.openjdk.nashorn</groupId>
  <artifactId>nashorn-core</artifactId>
  <version>15.1</version>
</dependency>
```